# Multiple Namespaces in a single line in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have a doubt to ask.

In C++, What do multiple namespaces in a single line refer to?

For example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio>

using namespace university::project::work ;
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: These are nested namespaces

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Do they work just like nested functions with their scopes limited to that block?

Comment: What do you mean by how they work? You are here using the namespace on which ` university::project::work` is referring to. Namespaces are something totally different then a function. Which scope do you mean and which block?

Answer (score 2):

Namespaces in C++ can be nested, thus the multiple namespaces you refer to.

Example:

```cpp
namespace foo {
    std::string cool_phrase;
    namespace bar {
        void func(int n) { ... }
    }
}

/* We will refer to cool_phrase as such: */
std::cout << foo::cool_phrase << std::endl;

/* We will call func as such: */
foo::bar::func(10);
```

This feature is not available in C++14 and before.

Answer (score 1):

For example if you have the following namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            int d;
        }               
    }
}
```

When you write `using namespace A::B::C;` you have a direct access to `d`.
If you have written `using namespace A;` you had to access `d` by `B::C::d`.

```
#include <iostream>
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        namespace C
        {
            int d;
        }               
    }
}
int main()
{
    using namespace A;
    B::C::d = 0; //OK
    C::d = 0; //NOT OK, C is not visible from A
    using namespace A::B;
    C::d = 0; //OK
    d = 0; //NOT OK
    using namespace A::B::C;
    d = 0; // OK
}
```